# sass-loader cannot understand @use with?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, sass-loader

I'm following https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use to try **@use with** inside Vue 2.6.x "sass": "^1.32.11", "sass-loader": "^10.1.0", and always get error when trying to import sass file into my Vue component

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                                                                                                friendly-errors 14:59:26  
SassError: expected "$".
  ╷
3 │ @use 'library' with (
  │                      ^
  ╵

  assets\css\fanclub.sass 3:22  @import
  pages\clb\_slug.vue 132:9     root stylesheet
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`@use` is not available with `node-sass` but with `sass` (aka `dart-sass`).
So, you need to install it (`yarn add -D sass`) and do a little configuration.

```js
/* vue.config.js */
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        implementation: require('sass')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As shown here: https://dev.to/matiaslopezd/how-to-use-dart-sass-with-vue-1m41

Comment: thanks. @use work just fine without with. I already got sass installed  "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",

Comment: So, `@use` is working or not? Not sure I get the thing here.

Comment: @use 'library' with (  => the error is at with.    @ use 'library'; is fine, I need to change the variable with 'with'
  │                      ^